# Erro ao compilar ola mundo

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib>

int main()
{
   printf("Ola Mundo!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Não consigo executar o programa no Ubuntu! Erro de compilação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get install gcc
```

Altere `#include <stdlib>`
para

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenta colocar `#include <stdio.h>` logo acima do código.

Answer (score 0):

Troque `#include <stdlib.h>` por `#include <stdio.h>`, pois a função `printf();` está na `stdio.h`, e não na `stdlib.h`.